# Datables Render Nested Objects & Arrays from Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this json from third party API, which isn't under my control-

```
https://pastebin.com/WNZZWXV7
```

(contains stripped down single set)

The 2 values I want in a row are like this-

Column 1 = response.listResults[0].listInstrument.instrumentBasic.symbol ("SAREGAMA" in the example)

Column 2 = response.listResults[0].listColumns[0].dataValue.doubleValue (823 in example)

This is my current code-

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>

<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '..private url',
        
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Stock", "data": "response.listResults.listInstrument.flagged", "searchable": true, "visible": true },
            { "title": "Price", "data": "response.listResults.listColumns[0].dataValue.doubleValue" }
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

I went through examples here - https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/ but not able to sort it out. Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a somewhat awkward JSON structure, because it has two separate arrays that you want to use as your iteration points for each DataTables column - and in the second column, you only want to take the first nested object...

Here is one approach:

Change your `ajax` option so it can use the [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option:

```js
"ajax": {
  "url": "..private url",
  "dataSrc": "response.listResults"
}
```

In this case, the `dataSrc` points to the location in your JSON response where the first JSON array starts: the `listResults` array.

Now you can use this as the starting point for each of your `columns` definitions:

```js
"columns": [
  { 
    "title": "Stock", 
    "data": "listInstrument.instrumentBasic.symbol", 
    "searchable": true, 
    "visible": true 
  },
  { 
    "title": "Price",
    "data": "listColumns.0.dataValue.doubleValue"
  }
]
```

The first column's data definition will iterate over every `listInstrument` object. But since there is only one such object, it will only grab the one related value for the symbol name: "SAREGAMA".

The second column uses `listColumns.0` to ensure it only looks at the first (of many) `listColumns` objects. That gives you the single price you want: 823. This obviously assumes you are OK hard-coding that zero, for the first object.

The end result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked for my json. I have accepted the answer.